# Selecting only the records where column value changes between rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to extract records from a table where the values in certain columns changes from one date to another date. I want to fetch records only for the dates when the values are changing.

```
ID  Value   Date
123 99  1/09/2019
123 99  2/09/2019
123 100 3/09/2019
123 100 4/09/2019
456 99  1/09/2019
456 100 2/09/2019
456 100 3/09/2019
456 100 4/09/2019
```

For ID "123", I want to fetch only the dates 02/09/2019 and 03/09/2019. For ID 456, I want to fetch onlly the dates 01/09/2019 and 02/09/2019.

Comment: What database are you using? If it's one that supports window functions, easy to do with `lag()` or `lead()`.

Comment: What is your DB product? Sql is only a language.

Comment: What abut gaps? Add (456, 200, 6/09/2019) to the sample table data. And also specify the expected result!

Comment: Its Oracle database

Comment: ID Value Date
123 99 2/09/2019
123 100 3/09/2019
456 99 1/09/2019
456 100 2/09/2019
456 200 6/09/2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

```
WITH bracketed AS 
  (SELECT id, value, date
        , lead(id) OVER bydate AS nextid
        , lead(value) OVER bydate AS nextval
        , lag(id) OVER bydate AS previd
        , lag(value) OVER bydate AS prevval
   FROM yourtable
   WINDOW bydate AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date))
SELECT id, value, date
FROM bracketed
WHERE (id = previd AND value <> prevval)
   OR (id = nextid AND value <> nextval)
ORDER BY id, date;
```

```
id          value       date      
----------  ----------  ----------
123         99          2019-09-02
123         100         2019-09-03
456         99          2019-09-01
456         100         2019-09-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
with cte as (
  select t1.id as id1, t1.date as d1, t1.val as val1, t2.id as id2, t2.val as val2, t2.date as d2 from 
  (select ID, val, date, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as rn
  from test) as t1
  join
  (select ID, val, date, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as rn
  from test) as t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.val != t1.val and t2.rn = t1.rn + 1
)
select * from (
select t1.* from cte c
inner join test t1 on t1.id=c.id1 and t1.val=c.val1 and t1.date = c.d1
union all
select t2.* from cte c
inner join test t2 on t2.id=c.id2 and t2.val=c.val2 and t2.date = c.d2)t
order by id, val
```

check [db_fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eaTL2ngGg6NvLRmwQrYc8u/0#&togetherjs=CVp4A6bVtV)